# How do I access uigetfile elements via a loop?

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface, image-processing

I have to perform the following steps on set of images via matlab GUI:

1. Read multiple images from directory
2. Process them (**Apply imadjust on each image**)
3. Store them in user specified or same directory while renaming them

Can someone kindly provide me the code for the same? I am stuck after this:

```
[filename, pathname,~] = uigetfile( ...
{'*.jpg;*.jpeg;',...
 'JPEG Files (*.jpg,*.jpeg)';
   '*.png',  'PNG files (*.png)'; ...
   '*.bmp','BMP File (*.bmp)'; ...
   '*.tiff;*.tif','TIFF Files (*.tiff,*.tif)'; ...
   '*.*',  'All Files (*.*)'}, ...
   'Pick a file',...
   'Multiselect','on');
set(handles.inputpathtext,'String',pathname);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[file_name_list, pathname] = uigetfile({'your filter spec','Multiselect','on');
```

The line above should give you a cell array containing the names of the files you selected. The following code loops through the cell array, read image, perform some adjustement, and save them with `'processed_'` prefix added to the file name in the same folder specified by `pathname`.

```
for ii = 1:length(file_name_list)
    if iscell(file_name_list)
        filename = file_name_list{ii};
    else
        filename = file_name_list;
    end
    img = imread(fullfile(pathname, filename));
    img = imadjust(img);  % Do something to the image
    imwrite(img, fullfile(pathname, ['processed_', filename])
end
```

Comment: The code works perfectly for Multiple Inputs. When i add a single file it gives error as : Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Comment: That's because when you have only one input, `file_name_list` would be a string but not cell array of string.  If you want to account for also single input, check if the returned file_name_list is a cell array, it not, treat it as string. See updated code.

Comment: Works Awesome. Thanks. Can you help me creating new directory? i want to save at pathname\converted. I tried using new_folder = strcat(pathname,'Converted\'); and  imwrite(img,fullfile(new_folder,['processed_',file_name_list]));

Comment: I'd suggest you do some homework  reading MATLAB documentation. You can easily find answer there.